# jQuery show/hide images on checking checkboxes

Tags: jquery, image, checkbox, hide, show

I have a table like this, and i have a checkbox at each row and checkboxes on each column. So i want to show/hide an tick mark image next to data in each td when i check the checkbox in the row and table headers. And the tick mark should hide when i uncheck.

Demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/MpzXU/3/

```
<table id="example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></h>
          <th>PO Number</th>
          <th>Hangtag<input type="checkbox" value="hangtag" class="ht_chkbx"/></th>
          <th>Care Label<input type="checkbox" value="Care Label" class="cl_chkbx"/></th>
          <th>UPC<input type="checkbox" value="UPC" class="upc_chkbx"/></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"></td>
          <td>6711112</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi Nahom, You're question seems so confusing. Please revise it so we can help you.

Comment: @Ian I have updated the question and put the demo also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/qLDan/) (edited to match comments)

I change the color of the text on checkbox change by adding a class.
For each  i check if both corresponding checkboxes (line and column) are unchecked before removing the class.

HTML

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A <input type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>B <input type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>C <input type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>D <input type="checkbox" /></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1 <input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>A4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 <input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>B4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>3 <input type="checkbox"></td>
         <td>C1</td>
         <td>C2</td>
         <td>C3</td>
         <td>C4</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

jQuery

```
var headers = $('#example th');
$(':checkbox', '#example').change(function(e){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if( $(this).closest('thead').length ){ //columns checkboxes
        //getting the column index
        var i = headers.index( $(this).parent() );

        $('tbody tr', '#example').each(function(){
            var isLineChecked = $(':checkbox:checked', this).length;

            if( isChecked && isLineChecked  ){
                $(this).find('td:eq('+i+')').addClass('selected');
            } else {
                $(this).find('td:eq('+i+')').removeClass('selected');
            }
        });

    } else { //line checkbox   
        var columnsCheckboxes = $(':checkbox', headers);

        $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(i, td){
            if( isChecked && columnsCheckboxes.eq(i).is(':checked') ){
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: GMO Thanks a lot, but what i need is when i select 1 and A, change should happen only to A1. Keeping 1 selected when i  select, 1 and B=A2, 1 and C=A3, 1 and D=A4 change should happen not for entire column....

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/qLDan/3/)  Modified the JSFiddle to do what you need.

Comment: Really, i should thank this entire thread for giving me lot of inputs,scripts, sharing thier knowledge. Infact this is my first jquery project which am developing enterprise application. Again KUDOS Stackoverflow and the entire developers across this site.... :)

Comment: @GMO I had encountered a small issue while implementing the logic. I have add 2 more columns before A,B,C,D cols. When i check for the 1st row, script is firing. But when i check for the subsequent row, the tick mark is coming in first columns also which i have added. Can you please look into the script again [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/qLDan/5/)

Comment: [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/qLDan/) I changed the siblings filter to do not take into account the added columns. Another possibility could have been to check for each cell if the corresponding header had a checkbox.

Comment: @GMO Is this the [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/qLDan/) one, for some reason the script is not working.

Comment: @Ravi working on my side. Try reloading without cache (CTRL + R or F5).

Comment: @GMO Working fine. I think the prb was firewall was blocking the image in my office.

Comment: @GMO Can you please help me in integrating your checkbox logic on to DataTables [Grid](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/MpzXU/11/) which i have developed. I have tried all the ways, but no luck. I am struggling from past few days. Would be great if you can help me on this. I have created a [thread](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=4502) also on DataTables forum.

Comment: @Ravi the plugin dupplicate the first column in another table... . I'm modifying the script to match the stupid markup.

Comment: @Ravi Ok done. The plugin is a real mess, it's altering the markup, dupplicates #ids, ... [updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmoulin/MpzXU/49/)

Comment: @GMO Seriously, i had very tough time understanding how to integrate the logic as I am just a beginner in js/jQuery. Thanks a ton man. I really owe you a party :). one last thing sorry :(, can we show the tick only if the td's are having data in it. I mean no to show tick on empty cells.

Comment: @GMO I don't know hw to thank you. Please buzz me if you need any help on Visual design/html/css/webapp design

Answer (score 2):

You would use something like this:

```
//Monitor the main checkbox ( $("#macDaddyCheckbox") ) for changes 
$("#macDaddyCheckbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        //It is checked, so hide the other checkboxes
        $(".babyCheckboxes").hide();
    } else {
        //It is not chceked, so show the other checkboxes
        $(".babyCheckboxes").show();
    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
var myImg = $("#myImg");

$("#checkBoxAtTheRow").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ myImg.hide(); } else { myImg.show(); }
});

$(".tableHeaderCheckBoxes").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ $(".babyCheckboxes").hide(); } else { $(".babyCheckboxes").show(); }
});
```

Comment: I want to show/hide an image when check/uncheck chekbox at the row and then select the table header checkboxes not to show/hide babycheckboxes..

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer that I could give you. Please check...

http://jsfiddle.net/MpzXU/9/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Ian, i got basic understanding. I will try to change the script implement what am looking for...

Comment: Your welcome :) Please vote if it helps or please don't forget to mark it with check if you find it as the right answer :)